# AWS Elasticsearch / Opensearch - Get Metrics On What's Being Searched

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I have an instance of Elasticsearch running in AWS OpenSearch.  From the documentation I've found online, AWS has something called OpenSearch Dashboards that is essentially their own forked version of Kibana.  This can be connected to my Elasticsearch instance to visualize data.

For OpenSearch Dashboards, all of the the guides I've found online deal with how we can visualize patterns in the underlying data (ie. what's the most popular keywords in an index column, etc...) or how we can visualize data about how the Elasticsearch service is running (ie. the CPU usage rate, the indexing rate, etc...).

Is there anyway for me to get statistics on and get visualizations for what's being searched and how often?  For example, I would like data on what unique search terms users have typed into our search bar in the past week, the number of times each of those unique terms have been searched, and the number of results each of these searches with that unique term have returned.